# how to override "def save_related()" in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Below is code for save_related() in django source code

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    """
    Given the ``HttpRequest``, the parent ``ModelForm`` instance, the
    list of inline formsets and a boolean value based on whether the
    parent is being added or changed, save the related objects to the
    database. Note that at this point save_form() and save_model() have
    already been called.
    """
    form.save_m2m()
    for formset in formsets:
        self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
```

I do not want my form to call save_formset for my inlines in admin,so I need to override save_related() method to avoid it.

I tried but didn't find the correct way to do it.

Comment: How about overriding this method and just `pass` it?

Comment: Tried it... Didn't work out

Comment: Did the answer below solved your issue? If yes, mark the answer as correct. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Comment: No , sorry didn't work out

Comment: Why is that? I tested it locally and works pretty well. Could you provide some examples? Or what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You should override the [`save_formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset) method, like this:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    formset.save(commit=False)
```

This way, the inlines will not be saved to the database each time the main object is saved via the admin.